# How can I remove element one by one on keypress?

Tags: jquery

When you enter value in the input and press Enter key, it will show up one by one and then when you press the backspace key, it will remove the whole div and I cannot enter any value again.

How can I remove the values one by one by removing the last one first. For example if I have 'dog, lion, cat, pig', when I press Backspace key, it will remove pig first, and then cat, then lion, last one dog. And when I enter bird, it will show up bird.

How can I achieve that?

```js
$("#input").keydown(function(event) {

  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //put input value into div
    var value = $('#input').val();
    $('#test2').text($('#test2').html() + " " + value);

  }
  //remove div when press backspace key
  if ($('#input').val() == '' && event.which == 8) {
    $('#test2').remove();
  }

});
```

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test" id="test0">dog</div>
<div class="test" id="test1">lion</div>
<div class="test" id="test2">cat</div>

<input type="text" id="input" />
```

Also http://jsfiddle.net/4y1b1j8g/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On press of the backspace key you want to delete the last `.test` element, for which you can use the `:last` selector.

I would also suggest that you amend the logic on enter press which is adding the text so that it appends a brand new `div` element, instead of putting it all inside the existing `#test2` div. This will then allow them to be deleted individually. Try this:

```
$("#input").keydown(function (e) {
    var $input = $('#input');
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<div />', { class: 'test', text: $input.val() }).insertBefore($input);
        $input.val(''); // remove the entered text from the input
    }
    else if ($input.val() == '' && e.which == 8) {
        $('.test:last').remove();
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4y1b1j8g/23/)

It's worth noting though that this is non-standard behaviour and may confuse your users.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
if(  $('#input').val() == ''  &&  event.which == 8){
                   var x = $('#test2').text(); console.log(x);
                   x= x.split(" ");
                   x.pop();
                   $('#test2').html(x.join(" "));
    }
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4y1b1j8g/22/)**